# Connection between span and linear dependancy for a set of vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, finite-fields, integers

The image of the proof (in Axler's book) has been attached onto this post.

My question/issue with the proof is that it assumes that each of $a_i/a_j, i \in \{1, \dots, j - 1\}$ is another element in the set where $a_i$ comes from. In the book, it is assumed that coefficients $a_i \in F$, where $F$ is either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$; in this case, the proof works. But if $a_i \in \mathbb{Z}$, for example, then this proof runs into a very obvious issue.[image]

I recall that earlier in the book, Axler notes that $F$ can represent any field, and since the set of integers $Z$ is not a field, this proof isn't meant to apply here?

Comment: Here, each $a_i$ is indeed an element of the scalar field, while $i$ belongs in $\Bbb{Z}$. The $i$s and $j$s are indexes, and indeed integers, but it makes perfect sense to divide $a_i$ and $a_j$, provided $a_j \neq 0$, to get another element of your scalar field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z}$ is not a field, so it is not a counterexample. The field axioms guarantee that $a_i/a_j$ is back in $F$ for any $a_i,a_j\in F$ with $a_j\neq0$.